# How do we prove the following binomial identity?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

$\sum\limits_{i=0,i\text{ is even}}^{n-1} i\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\i\end{array}\right)p^{(n-i)}(1-p)^i=\left\{\begin{array}{c}n(1-p)\left(1-(1-2 p)^{(n-1)}\right), n \text{ is odd}\\n(1-p)\left(1+(1-2 p)^{(n-1)}-2(1-p)^{(n-1)}\right), n \text{ is even}\end{array}\right.$

I tried to prove it by expanding the left hand side, but to no avail. Can you please explain me how to prove this statement?

I'm thinking calculus(differentiation) can be used to prove this, as there is an 'i' prepended to the expression of 'i'th term of LHS. But, I need a clue. Please direct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the binomial expansion of $(p+x)^n=\sum_i \binom{n}{i} p^{n-i}x^i $

Consider

\begin{equation}
(p+x)^n+(p-x)^n=2\sum_{i=0,\mbox{i is even}}^n \binom{n}{i} p^{n-i}x^i
\end{equation}

Now take derivative wrt $x$ on both sides and then multiply both sides by $x$.   Substitute $x=1-p$ and move a few terms around and you should get the answer, although I think a factor of 2 is missing in your answer.

Comment: Perfect! This is what I was looking for. Many thanks :)
Where do we find (book) all such kinds of binomial identities?

Comment: Check out this book https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf   It is a classic text for generating function based methods.

Comment: Hi There! Thanks for the reference you provided. I edited the (p-x^n) in the above solution you provided to (p-x)^n. But, unfortunately it's a two character edit and as per stackexchange rules the edit should be at least 6 characters. I made some superflous, but sensible edits at some other place. Sorry to say this but, two dumb reviewers have have rejected it saying that edit is totally superfluous. Kindly, edit the solution yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if $n$ is odd, say $n=2k+1,$ then the right-hand side can be rewritten as $$(2k+1)(1-p)\left(\bigl((1-p)+p\bigr)^{2k}-\bigl((1-p)+(-p)\bigr)^{2k}\right).$$ Try applying the Binomial Theorem to $\bigl((1-p)+p\bigr)^{2k}$ and $\bigl((1-p)-p\bigr)^{2k}$ and see what you can do from there.

Similarly, if $n=2k,$ then the right-hand side can be rewritten as $$2k(1-p)\left(\bigl((1-p)+p\bigr)^{2k-1}+\bigl((1-p)-p\bigr)^{2k-1}-2(1-p)^{2k-1}\right).$$ Once again, we can start by applying Binomial Theorem to the respective powers of $(1-p)+p$ and $(1-p)-p.$